Loading TWO existing .html file with android webview in android studio
I am new to Android Studio, I tried to load  index.html using web view and it worked as expected but when I tried to load home.html it didn't load in the emulator
I want to load index.html.I also want to load home.html which I put in the assets folder with a hyperlink in the index.html page
In the current code the index.html loads perfectly fine but when clicking the hyperlink, it gives this error

The web page at file:///android_asset/home.html could not be loaded because:
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND'

I checked the file location and it was the same, I tried to load home.html the same way as I did with index.html but none solved it
I then replaced the home.html with a CSS file and it found the file and gave the result even though the html file in the same folder couldn't be found
I will share my mainactivity.java and index.html here
// MainActivity.java
package com.example;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");


    }
}

// index.html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding-top:20"><center><a href="home.html">Go to Home Page</a></center></div>
</body>
</html>

I do not have much experience with coding and English is not my main language, so please make the explanation simple

file:///andriod_asset/home.html -- there is a typo. You have andriod instead of android.

Sorry that was just a typo.Can you make sure that there is no typo in the actual code (mainactivity.java and index.html).I accidentally typed the wrong spelling of android when copying the error.For clarification,it doesnt fix the problem
